# How to install TestSwarm on Windows?

Tags: configuration, wamp, filepath, overriding, testswarm

I am following the [installation instructions for TestSwarm](https://github.com/jquery/testswarm) on Windows. I've installed the [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/).

The second step of the TestSwarm installation is to override a `localSettings.php` file, but I cannot find such a file in the WampServer installation. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

The `localSettings.php` file is part of TestSwarm, not WAMP. Do the following:

- Find the `testswarm` folder
- Find the `config` subfolder
- Find the `sample-localSettings.php` file
- Copy it
- Paste it
- Rename the new file `localSettings.php`